# How can I find a check for a converging value more efficiently in python

Tags: python, math

I'm trying to estimate the value of pi up to 3 d.p but it feels extremely slow, for example it takes almost 20 minutes to loop 10,000 times. I'm assuming because it keeps individually checking every single value so I was wondering if there's anyway to loop faster since I need to find a better average.

```py
def est(b,a,d,c):
    total=0
    count=0
    dp=False
    while not dp:
        count+=1
        x,y=random.uniform(a,b),random.uniform(c,d)
        if x**2+y**2<1:
            total+=1
        areaest=((abs(b-a)*abs(d-c))/count)*total
        round=float("{:.3f}".format(areaest))
        if round==3.142:
            dp=True
    return count
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using this method of calculating pi? But yes, there is no reason for you to be calculating abs(b - a) * abs(d - c) inside your loop.  Also your method of rounding (converting to a string and then back to a float) is also really slow.   Just use the `round()` function.

Comment: I'm using this method since my task requires me to use Monte-Carlo sampling, would there be a more efficient method you know of?

Comment: If you're required to use Monte Carlo, then this is the method.  But there are other equations that converge to π much more quickly. This method of finding π is more of a curiosity rather than being useful in practice.

Comment: There are many ways to speed it, but I think you need to say more about how you're running this that it's so slow to begin with. Which version of Python? Under what are you running it (command shell, fancy environment, ...)? _Exactly_ how do you invoke it (e.g., what are `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d`)? On my box, a desktop Win10 running Python 3.10.1, it takes under a second for `est(1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0)` to complete, and `count` at the end varies across a wide range (I've seen it anywhere from 247 to 12011).

Comment: @TimPeters: My understanding was that the OP was running `est(1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0)` (or something like it) 10000 times. I think the problem is that the distribution on the `count` result has extremely high variance, so if you're unlucky it's easy for some of those 10000 runs to end up needing a count of many hundreds of millions or more. The fact that the acceptance interval of `(3.1415, 3.1425)` is not centered around π isn't helping, either.

Comment: I'm using spyder (python 3.7) to run this. And I execute it with
`n=[]
for i in range(1000):
    n.append(est(1,-1,1,-1))
print(statistics.mean(n))`

Comment: Trying this on my own laptop, 10000 runs did indeed take many minutes, and the topmost counts were `[39053964, 45184765, 49741666, 71541252, 73843080, 79242982, 84929030, 86923066, 221441664, 328360280]`

Comment: It should be a simple application of the central limit theorem to establish that the chance of needing a count larger than 1 billion (say) amongst 10000 runs is non-negligible.

Comment: Ah, so the "loop" you wrote about in your question was _not_ the loop shown in your code. My telepathy failed in this case ;-)

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an `O()` improvement to be had. Monte Carlo methods rely on trying things many, many times.

There are lots of low-level ways to cut cycles, though, which you pick up by experience. For example, move invariant computations out of loops, multiply once instead of raising to the power 2, use float literals where appropriate instead of integer literals that you *know* will have to be converted to float every time ... Here's a version with a bunch of those:

```py
def est(b, a, d, c):
    from random import uniform
    box_area = float(abs(b-a) * abs(d-c))
    total = count = 0
    while True:
        count += 1
        x, y = uniform(a, b), uniform(c, d)
        if x*x + y*y < 1.0:
            total += 1
        areaest = box_area / count * total
        if abs(areaest - 3.142) < 0.0005:
            break
    return count
```

BTW, a meta-comment: why are you checking for convergence to 3.142 at all? In a Monte Carlo application, you typically don't know the result you're looking for in advance. If you did, why bother running Monte Carlo?

More typical: you pick a fixed number of iteration to run in advance. Then average over many runs each using that fixed number of iterations. Timing is at least roughly predictable then.